# .htaccess Redirect Endless Loop

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site with a long path of http://www.example.com/academic-solutions/resources/title-of-content/ that I would like to redirect to http://www.example.com/title-of-content/. I'm using the following code in my .htaccess file, which appears to actually be performing the correct redirect, but it results in an infinite loop for some reason. Any reason this code is causing an infinite loop?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/academic-solutions/resources/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this matters, this is a Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `%` in the last line with `$`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but now I am being redirected to the homepage whenever I try to access http://www.example.com/academic-solutions/resources/title-of-content/